# is this a function pointer array as function parameter?

Tags: c++

In some standard header file, I encountered something like this:

```
template <class _Tp> char __test(_Tp (*)[1]);
```

I don't quite understand the parameter defined inside. From '(*)' it tells it's a function ptr, but it followed by '[1]' instead of function parameter declaration. Any one can please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: It's an unnamed pointer to an array containing one element of type `_Tp`. It's not a function pointer.

Comment: [Try this.](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*x%29%5B1%5D)

Comment: @0x499602D2 It looks like that tool doesn't support C++ template declarations.

Comment: This declares a template function `_test` that takes a pointer-to-array-of- one `_Tp` as the sole input parameter. There is no pointer-to-function involved in this (unless `_Tp` is deduced as such, but that likely isn't what you intended).

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that this is not a function pointer but a pointer to an array.